# Solving algebra word problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man has a set of jacks.  He has $j$ jacks, which is twice as many jacks as he has balls $b$ . How many balls does he have?

Correct answer $b=\frac{j}{2}$.  I think it should be $b=2j$ because he has "twice as many jacks as he has balls".

Comment: What does $j$ stand for?

Comment: $j$ is the number of jacks.

Comment: He has twice as many jacks as he has balls, so $j = 2b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b=2j$, that implies that he has more jacks than balls. However, from the problem, you know that he has more jacks than balls, so the answer should be $b=\frac{j}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If he has $5$ balls, how many jacks does he have?  $10$?  Then $5 = \frac{10}{2}.$